# How Do I Push A URL's Code To A Git Repository?

Tags: javascript, git, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

I'm a Git newbie.

I have a BitBucket account, and I have Atlassian SourceTree installed on my Windows 7 PC.

Periodically, I ask our IRT team to put fresh code up at www.example.com/extrajs/myscript.js

I'm not interested in tracking any copies of the data on my own PC - I just want to have a button I can click that will copy whatever is currently at www.example.com/extrajs/myscript.js into my repository.

Is it possible to copy directly from the web to a Git repository?  If so, how?  (SourceTree-specific or BitBucket-web-UI-specific answers even better!  I like to avoid the command line when possible.)

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by 'leaving traces behind on my PC'

Comment: I mean that I'd rather not be downloading the file to my PC and then pushing it to BitBucket.  I want a "smooth" way to take a URL on the web & push its contents into BitBucket w/o having an "intermediate" step on my PC that I might forget to clean up from / do the next time.  Edited o.p.

Comment: Sounds like a simple bash script, what have you tried yourself so far?

Comment: I created a new repository in BitBucket & clicked the buttons to set it up in SourceTree.  The SourceTree side asked me for a path on my PC.  That's as far as I got.  (I haven't gotten as far as actually UNDERSTANDING Git enough to make up command-line interactions with BitBucket.  Thus far, it's all just been following instructions for point-and-click using instructions from blog posts (for example, Salesforce code to BitBucket).  I suppose in the Salesforce case, I have to hop through my computer's hard drive (via Eclipse) ... I guess it makes sense I would have to do so here, too?

Comment: A file can't be pushed to a repo in isolation. It needs to be part of a tree, which needs to be part of a commit, which needs to be related to other commits in the repository. This requires a local copy of at least part of the repository, even if it's just in-memory. (But if it's just in-memory, that will require fetching it from the server every time.) This is all possible, but it's not the kind of workflow that these tools are designed for, and I wouldn't bet on anything providing this functionality directly out-of-the-box.

Comment: Great - thanks so much, Nit & Jeremy !  Looks like I'm off to figure it out with scripting.

Bummer everyone thinks my o.p. apparently sucks, but at least I got a good answer ... thanks to those everyone patient enough with me to work through this.  :-)

@JeremyBanks, if you want to repost your comment as an answer, I can "check" it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the general case<sup>1</sup>, a file can't be pushed to a repo in isolation. It needs to be part of a tree, which needs to be part of a commit, which needs to be related to other commits in the repository. This requires a local copy of at least some parts of the repository, even if it's just in-memory.

If you don't want a persistent local copy, the tool would need to fetch some information from the repository each time you want to push an update, so it knows how to structure it. This could be done, but it's quite far from the workflow that most distributed version control systems are designed for. Unfortunately, this means that it's unlikely that any tools will provide functionality like this right out-of-the-box. I haven't heard of anything like this from GitHub or BitBucket.

It would probably be necessary for you to write a custom script to handle this. If you're worried about forgetting to clean it up (and accidentally pushing inconsistent/stale data), I suggest using an OS API to use a unique temporary folder each time you run the script, such as `mktemp -d` on Linux. You should also be aware of `git clone`'s `--shallow-clone` option, which allows you to only clone the most recent commits of a repository, letting you make changes without requiring the entire history to be redownloaded.

<sup><sup>1</sup> Some Git servers are really just standard Linux machines which you're using a standard SSH connection to interact with, potentially with broad permissions. In cases like this, it may be possible to upload the file to the server using SSH/SFTP, and the commit it directly on the server. However, this type of configuration has become rare, and I would recommend against it.</sup>